# Can I display friends ids on comment, programatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website that interacts with the Facebook API. 
Basically, when you login (with you facebook account) it fetches all your friends and let you select them, and put them on a list.

The thing is, then, you can share this to facebook (with a "recommend" button).

Then, what I want to do is that, when you recommend this on facebook, the users from that list, appears tagged on the comment, or the site meta data, etc.

It is possible? Plus, it is possible to call the "recommend" button, with a default text, so the user do not need to type in??

Thanks!

Comment: Facebook is pretty protective of people doing things like that, I'm sure you can not force the recommend without clicking a seperate button, and you probably are going to have trouble pulling their friends id's and adding them to a comment

Comment: And what about show them in the meta-tags attributes of the link?
I am showing the users names but, it displays them like text and, I think that show them like tags would be usefull and harmless...

Answer (score 0):

read this - It expalins how to get a list of friend's ID's

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)

EDIT:

here [tag-user-facebook-graph](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/)

Comment: assuming it sounds like you already have read_friendlists permission since you already have their text names

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I already fill a combo with the user's friends names (using a FQL query), and I can get their IDs. What I need is that, when they hit the recommend button, the message on facebook appears with the friends tagged (the ones the user select from that combo)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I already saw that link before (doing some google search) but, I could not get it work. I tried with my user:

@[1101722784:1:Martin Cerdeira]

But, nothing happens...

Comment: It seems like facebook removes all posibilities of doing this, via Send, Feed or Like dialog. The closest thing is to send a "feed", but it can be set to only one user... It's a shitty API, I don't like it anymore =)